# id-expressions denoting non-static data members in templates

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[class.mfct.non-static] p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non-static#3) says that id-expressions denoting members are implicitly transformed into member access expressions, and notably it mentions that this does not happen in the context of a template definition. Given this code:

```
template<typename>
struct S
{
  int a;
  void f()
  {
    ++a;
  }
}
```

According to [[expr.prim.id] p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#2), such an id-expression is not allowed to appear here, as it is not a member access expression, explicit or implicit.

Is this wording defective? Or does [class.mfct.non-static] p3 apply after instantiation, and therefore this wording is ok?

Comment: Rules for templates are spelled out [elsewhere](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type#5.1).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, so the names are first checked prior to instantiation, and once the specialization is instantiated, the semantic rules for a class apply, right?

Comment: For templates, name lookup is performed twice - once while processing the template definition, and again during instantiation. It is the former that is referred to as "template definition context". In the latter, normal rules apply. The special case is needed because, under two-phase lookup rules, `a` works differently from `this->a` (the former is not a dependent name, the latter is), and the transformation may produce different results.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, but the semantic constraints for a class must be checked at some point. Once the specialization is instantiated, they are checked, and all the rules for normal classes apply, right?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You can post your second comment as an answer.  This allows it to be voted upon.